# Get Phone Number From Android Mobile Application

Tags: java, android

I want to know, how we get mobile number of same device on which android application is running.

I follow this link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9A_bHH9blZE.

In which I use

uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" in <> tag

in manifeast.xml file of application.

And Use TelephonyManager class to get number as

TalaphonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

String number = tm.getLine1Number();

in onCreate method of MyActivity.java file.

**BUT** I get blank in number field.

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: are you actually dumping the value of `number` anywhere? like to logcat or setting it to a textview? how do you know the number isn't being pulled properly?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code which you posted there seems to be nothing wrong and this behaviour is mentioned in api for `getLine1Number()`

> Returns the phone number string for line 1, for example, the MSISDN
>   for a GSM phone. Return null if it is unavailable.